# Do I have to catch errors within a Promise constructor?

Tags: javascript

I know I can call `reject()` when I detect a problem to reject the Promise, but am I supposed to use `try/catch` to catch errors too? Which of these is right?

```
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = dangerousMethod(...);
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Or:

```
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let data = dangerousMethod(...);
            resolve(data);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

My intuition tells me maybe I don't have to do it, but my intuition gets me in a lot of trouble when I'm writing JS.

Comment: What sort of exception are you expecting to be thrown?

Comment: Why are you using `readFileSync` with promises?

Comment: how about [`util.promisify(fs.readFile)(...).then(doSomething)`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)?

Comment: Why are you not directly using [`fsPromises.readFile(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) ?

Comment: Felix, ever better. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: But to answer your question, running `new Promise(() => {throw new Error('foo')})` on the console shows that promises get automatically rejected when an error inside the executor is thrown.

Comment: fs.readFileSync() was the first, obvious method I could think of that might throw an exception. I'll edit it to something that isn't so objectionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise will be rejected automatically if an exception is raised, here's the relavant bit from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Syntax):

> A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The
>   executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
>   implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is
>   called before the Promise constructor even returns the created
>   object). The resolve and reject functions, when called, resolve or
>   reject the promise, respectively. The executor normally initiates some
>   asynchronous work, and then, once that completes, either calls the
>   resolve function to resolve the promise or else rejects it if an error
>   occurred. **If an error is thrown in the executor function, the promise
>   is rejected.** The return value of the executor is ignored.

Comment: Cool, I missed that sentence when I was looking over the docs. Thanks!