# Node: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working through a js/node workshop on async programming called promise-it-wont-hurt. I have the following exercise:

- Some invalid JSON will be available on process.argv[2].
- Build a function called `parsePromised` that creates a promise,performs
- `JSON.parse` in a `try`/`catch` block, and fulfills or rejects the promise depending on whether an error is thrown. **Note:** your function should synchronously return the promise!
- Build a sequence of steps like the ones shown above that catchesany thrown errors and logs them to the console.

my answer:

```
function parsePromised(json) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      resolve( JSON.parse(json) ),
      reject(throwError)
  });

}

parsePromised(process.argv[2]).then(console.log);
```

The stack trace is:

```
(node:3499) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at /home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/promise-shop/test.js:184:21
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at parsePromised (/home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/promise-shop/test.js:183:10)
```

and the exercise result gives:

```
Your solution to Throw an error didn't pass. Try again!
```

Any idea how to get this working?

after changing to code in answer , the stack trace:

```
(node:5533) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: 
 Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at /home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/promise-shop/test.js:186:34
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at parsePromised (/home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/promise-shop/test.js:184:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/promise-shop/test.js:196:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
(node:5533) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Have a look at how the function within Promise should look like [as explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), To give you a hint, you need to write a try block where you parse the JSON and call `resolve` with that JSON. In catch block, if parsing fails, you call `reject` with an `Error`

Comment: Re-read step #3. You should be parsing the JSON and resolving the promise in a `try` block

Comment: Well, were's your try/catch block? It's in the instructions you pasted here!

Comment: Then only catch resolved cases, let's chain it with `.catch`

Comment: @Faust No `try`/`catch` is necessary inside a `new Promise` executor. That part of the exercise doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the instruction you mentioned, I think you want to do it this way

```
function parsePromised(json) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     try {
         const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
         resolve(parsedJson);
     } catch(error) {
        // we reach in this block if we encounter error while parsing some invalid given json
        reject(error);
        //or reject(error.message);
     }
  });
}
```

Now you call it like this

```
parsePromised(process.argv[2])
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("some error occured while parsing the json");
        console.log("error is:", err.message);
    });
```

basically whatever you rejected in the promise goes to catch higher order function when you try to get the promise result.

Comment: @user1592380 you have to add  a catch block in you promise handling of the function returning the promise using  a catch, updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there, you only missed the last step:

> Build a sequence of steps like the ones shown above **that catches** any thrown errors and logs them to the console.

You were only logging the result if it was not an error. Change it to

```
parsePromised(process.argv[2]).catch(console.log);
//                             ^^^^^
```

Notice also that you don't need to explicitly call `reject` - [the `Promise` constructor already handles exceptions thrown from the executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52633324/1048572). So all you need to do is

```
function parsePromised(json) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve( JSON.parse(json) )
  });
}
```

If you wanted to catch the error yourself, you'd rather write

```
function parsePromised(json) {
  try {
    return Promise.resolve( JSON.parse(json) );
  } catch(thrownError) {
    return Promise.reject(thrownError);
  }
}
```